# emberjs | beforeModel hook is firing after model hook

Tags: ember.js

I have a mixin with following definition.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Mixin.create({

  loggedinUser: {},
  beforeModel() {  

    if (!this.get('AuthService').isAuthenticated()) {
       this.transitionTo('login');
    }

    this.get('AuthService').getLoggedinUser()
    .then(results => {this.loggedinUser = results;
      alert("in before model"); 
    alert(this.loggedinUser.requestorId);    
    });     
  } }
});
```

I import it in my route as following

```
import UnAuthenticatedRouteMixin from '../mixins/un-authenticated-route-mixin';

export default Ember.Route.extend(UnAuthenticatedRouteMixin, {

  model(){  
    this._super(...arguments);

    alert("in model");
    alert(this.loggedinUser.requestorId); 

  }
});
```

My expected order of alerts is   "in before model "  -> "1234", "in model" , "1234". However the actual order of alerts is   "in model "  -> "undefined", "in before model" , "1234"

How can I ensure that beforeModel hook is fired after model hook.

Comment: Give the [Asynchronous Routing](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.18.0/routing/asynchronous-routing/#toc_the-router-pauses-for-promises) section of the guides a look ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One workaround that I am applying to force the order is to return promise from the beforeModel hook so that model hook wait for resolution of that promise. The mixin code changes to as mentioned below. However, is there a better way to handle this scenario?

```
   import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Mixin.create({

  loggedinUser: {},
  beforeModel() {  

    if (!this.get('AuthService').isAuthenticated()) {
       this.transitionTo('login');
    }

    return this.get('AuthService').getLoggedinUser()
    .then(results => {this.loggedinUser = results;
      alert("in before model"); 
    alert(this.loggedinUser.requestorId);    
    });     
  } }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is that the `beforeModel` hook is executed before the `model` hook, but the promise returned from `getLoggedinUser` returnes later.

The router however will wait for promises to resolve, so the solution is simple: just return the promise!

So replace this:

```
this.get('AuthService').getLoggedinUser()
  .then(results => {this.loggedinUser = results;
    alert("in before model"); 
    alert(this.loggedinUser.requestorId);    
  });
```

with this:

```
return this.get('AuthService').getLoggedinUser()
  .then(results => {this.loggedinUser = results;
    alert("in before model"); 
    alert(this.loggedinUser.requestorId);    
  });
```